# Project with serde cannot compile

Tags: rust, serde

When I try to run the example [from the serde repository](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde):

```
#![feature(proc_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

extern crate serde_json;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 1, y: 2 };

    // Convert the Point to a JSON string.
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&point).unwrap();

    // Prints serialized = {"x":1,"y":2}
    println!("serialized = {}", serialized);

    // Convert the JSON string back to a Point.
    let deserialized: Point = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();

    // Prints deserialized = Point { x: 1, y: 2 }
    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

I get an error:

> error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific
>   information
>
> Caused by:   process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name _
>   --print=file-names --crate-type bin --crate-type proc-macro --crate-type rlib --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` (exit code: 101)
>   --- stderr error: unknown crate type: `proc-macro`

My Rust version is 1.13.0 and my Cargo.toml has these dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
serde = "*"
serde_derive = "*"
```

Should I use other dependencies or extra configuration?

Comment: You need to use nightly, and a recent one at that, and you should not be using `"*"` dependencies but specify versions. If you want to use stable, you need to use the solution described here: https://serde.rs/codegen-stable.html

Comment: @ker do you mean rustc nightly? which version of serde and serde_derive could you recommend me?

Comment: Yes I mean rustc nightly. Unfortunately the feature will be unstable for another release cycle or two, so 1.5 to 3 months until you can use it in stable. The suggested versions are those that you can find on https://serde.rs or simply the most recent on on crates.io

Answer (score 1):

The `#![feature(...)]` attribute indicates code that uses Rust features which have not been stabilized yet. At the time the question was asked, the `proc_macro` feature was not yet stable. Serde needs this feature for its `#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]` macros.

Custom derives have been stabilized as of [Rust 1.15](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/02/02/Rust-1.15.html) so the code in the question (with the feature attribute removed) should work on any Rust compiler since that version.